# Why ElapsedTicks of Stopwatch in C# is collapsed?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I want to know why the *ElapsedTicks* value(s) difference is changing just because of changing the *region*.

### Code

```
 Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch( );
 #region "TimeCheck1"
 timer.Start( );
 string s1 = "HelloWorld";
 int length = s1.Length;
 int subLength = length / 2;
 string sA = s1.Substring(0, subLength);
 string sB = s1.Substring(subLength, subLength);
 timer.Stop( );
 Console.WriteLine("String: " + s1 + " Sub1: " + sA + " Sub2: " + sB + " Timer: " + timer.ElapsedTicks);
 #endregion "TimeCheck1"

 #region "TimeCheck2"
 timer.Start( );
 string s2 = "HelloWorld";
 int length2 = s2.Length;
 int subLength2 = length2 / 2;
 string s2A = subStr(s2, 0, subLength2);
 string s2B = subStr(s2, subLength2, subLength2);
 timer.Stop( );
 Console.WriteLine("String: " + s2 + " Sub1: " + s2A + " Sub2: " + s2B + " Timer: " + timer.ElapsedTicks);
 #endregion "TimeCheck2"
```

### Output 1

```
String: HelloWorld Sub1: Hello Sub2: World Timer: 12
String: HelloWorld Sub1: Hello Sub2: World Timer: 639
```

### Output 2

after interchanging regions TimeCheck1 and TimeCheck2

```
String: HelloWorld Sub1: Hello Sub2: World Timer: 826
String: HelloWorld Sub1: Hello Sub2: World Timer: 828
```

Why this difference occurs? I'm too confused here.

### Edit ( I hope, this method is not an issue)

```
private static string subStr( string str, int index, int len ) {
    string sub = "";
    int c = index;
    len = index + len;
    while( c != len ) {
        sub += str[ c ];
        c++;
    }
    return sub;
}
```

Comment: That's because of the High Res. Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Arghya Thats my own function. But that is not an issue. If you interchange the region blocks, the difference is like > 500.

Comment: @Kevintjuh93. I think you didn't get my point. Just run the program and run again by interchanging the regions block. The differences are high.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV There can always be little variation, but should not be this big. Did you [1] Repeat it multiple times? [2] Debug while testing?

Comment: @NaveenKumarV in that case. It does matter what 'subStr' is. Also how often did you run the test? The timer can sometimes 'lagg' a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the StopWatch wrongly. You should call Restart() on the second call, not Start(). If you change it then you get consistent result in your measures

From MSDN [StopWatch.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When a Stopwatch instance measures more than one interval, the Start
>   method resumes measuring time from the current elapsed time value. A
>   Stopwatch instance calculates and retains the cumulative elapsed time
>   across multiple time intervals, until the instance is reset. Use the
>   Reset method before calling Start to clear the cumulative elapsed time
>   in a Stopwatch instance. Use the Restart method to Reset and Start the
>   Stopwatch with a single command.

```
 Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch( );
 timer.Start( );

 #region "TimeCheck1"
 .....
 #endregion "TimeCheck1"

 timer.Restart( );
 #region "TimeCheck2" 
 ....
 #endregion
```

Now if you invert the regions the measurements are coehrent. And you can see that your subStr takes a performance hit on its first run.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Stopwatch` depends on OS and hardware.

From [Stopwatch.IsHighResolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The timer used by the Stopwatch class depends on the system hardware and operating system. IsHighResolution is true if the Stopwatch timer is based on a high-resolution performance counter. Otherwise, IsHighResolution is false, which indicates that the Stopwatch timer is based on the system timer.

The more ticks per interval, the higher the resolution. Which means the `Stopwatch` will be much more accurate.

Edit: As CodeCaster mentioned, sometimes the `Stopwatch` has to warm-up. Probably because it uses hardware in the High Resolution state. From my experience I can tell you it is true. Try starting only one Stopwatch. And calculate the difference between ticks (current - start). It might also help to add a sleep after the Start.

Comment: The difference in first case is low. But the difference in second case is high always. Try putting TimeCheck1 under TimeCheck2 Region, I dont get what is happening !

Comment: @Naveen the regions are irrelevant, their sole purpose is to make source code collapsible. They are not compiled or anything. You're benchmarking JITted code, try reading about how to do that properly. You're probably looking at warmup times.

Comment: Well I use the `Stopwatch` class often too. Try having only one `Stopwatch`. Save the amount of ticks it started. And then do `ElapsedTicks - startTicks`

Like CodeCaster said, it has to warmup most of the times. I have that too, that's why I run my Stopwatch when I start my program. So whenever I use it, it's accurate 'enough'.

Comment: @CodeCaster I know the purpose of  <i>#region</i>. What I dont understand is why the difference becomes high, if I put <i>TimeCheck1</i> under <i>TimeCheck2</i>.